# Rails: Why am I getting the wrong link on this pingback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, trackback, pingback

So I almost have a pingback sender ready for my rails app (people post links to content and donate to them). Almost.

I've borrowed heavily from the code here:
http://theadmin.org/articles/2007/12/04/mephisto-trackback-library/

I modified the slightly for my purposes:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

class Trackback

  @data = { }

  def initialize(link_id)
    link = Link.find(link_id)
    site = Link.website

    if link.nil?
      raise "Could not find link"
    end

    if link.created_at.nil?
      raise "link not published"
    end

    @data =  {
      :title => link.name,
      :excerpt => link.description,
      :url => "http:://www.MyApp.org/links/#{link.to_param}/donations/new",
      :blog_name => "My App"
    }
  end

  def send(trackback_url)
    u = URI.parse trackback_url
    res = Net::HTTP.start(u.host, u.port) do |http|
      http.post(u.request_uri, url_encode(@data), { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' })
    end
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "TRACKBACK: #{trackback_url} returned a response of #{res.code} (#{res.body})"
    return res
  end

  private

  def url_encode(data)
    return data.map {|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')
  end

end
```

Looks like I'm sending links successfully to my wordpress blog but when I look at the link displayed on the trackback I get this: http://www.theurl.com/that/my/browser/iscurrentlypointing/at/http:://www.MyApp.org/links/#{link.to_param}/donations/new"

All I want is the second half of this long string. Don't know why the current location on my browser is sneaking in there.

I've tried this on two of my blogs so it doesn't seem to be problem related to my wordpress installation.

UPDATE: Okay this is a little odd: I checked the page source and it shows the correct link. When I click on it, however, I get directed to the weird link I mentioned above. Is this a Wordpress Issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! Looks like it was just a syntax error. A sneaky double colon

This line

```
url => "http:://www.MyApp.org/links/#{link.to_param}/donations/new"
```

Should of course be like this

```
url => "http://www.MyApp.org/links/#{link.to_param}/donations/new",
```